# How do i make an xsd gYear element optional

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Have an xml file and i want both these types to be valid

```
<releaseYear>2032</releaseYear>  OR
<releaseYear></releaseYear>
```

Now, I have tried the following at the XSD

```
<xs:element name="releaseYear" type="xs:gYear" minOccurs="0"/> OR
<xs:element name="releaseYear" type="xs:gYear" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>   OR
<xs:element name="releaseYear" type="xs:gYear" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

None of those worked.
The Only thing that makes the XSD Validate against the XML is that i set the type as `xs:string` like so

```
<xs:element name="releaseYear" type="xs:string"/>
```

But thats not the right way to do it, Any suggestions on making it validate for a Year or ''

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
<xs:element name="releaseYear" type="xs:gYear" nillable="true"/>
```

the following XML is valid for the above Schema.

```
<releaseYear>2032</releaseYear> or
<releaseYear xsi:nil="true"/>
```

see [XML Schema nillable=”true” vs minOccurs=”0″](http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/08/18/xml-schema-nillabletrue-vs-minoccurs0/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach is to define a list type with `gYear` as the itemType and with `minLength=0`, `maxLength=1`.